# php add a new data in a json tree

Tags: php, json

How can I add new data to a JSON structure?

Here is the JSON in `json.txt`:

```
[
 {"name":"foo","number":"1"},
 {"name":"bar","number":"2"},
 {"name":"Hello","number":"3"}
]
```

Now I want to add a new line `{"name":"good day","number":"**"}`

```
$file = 'json.txt';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
$newdata = array('name'=>'good day', 'number' => '**');// how to add `number` automatic `+1`, make it to `4` with php code?
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: your code looks ok, what do you get as output?

Comment: 4 because it will be the fourth entry in the array, or because it's the max number (3) + 1?

Comment: @Yoshi, if I add more datas in this `txt`, and how to insert the number automaticlly increase?

Comment: "Data" is already the plural of "datum".

Comment: It looks to me like this `number` property should not exist. The subobjects already have a natural ordering, so remove the redundant and hard-to-maintain `number` field and lose nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = 'json.txt';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
$newNumber = max(array_map(
   function($e) {return intval($e['number']);},
$data)) + 1;
$newdata = array('name'=>'good day', 'number' => strval($newNumber));
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

In php < 5.3, replace the `$newNumber =` statement with:

```
$newNumber = max(array_map(
    create_function('$e', 'return intval($e["number"]);'),
$data)) + 1;
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ') on line 4

Comment: @fish man I'm assuming you're testing with an old php version. Updated the answer with code that should work for php<5.3 too.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the number is continuous. Why not use `end` make the number auto increase?

```
<?php
$file = 'json.txt';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
$number = (end($data)->number) + 1;
$newdata = array('name'=>'good day', 'number' => ''.$number.''); // how to add `number` automatic `+1`, make it to `4` with php code?
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
?>
```